# NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, flipkart-api

I am trying to do a simple GET request to flipkart search api.

```
  baseurl= 'https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/search/json?';
  params={
    query:name,
    resultCount:5
  };
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET',baseurl+$.param(params),false);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Fk-Affiliate-Id","myidhere");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Fk-Affiliate-Token","mytokenhere");
  xhr.send();
```

[image]
After using asynchronous XMLHttpRequest(),I get following error:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", baseurl+$.param(params), true);
  xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log("gowofee",xhr.responseText);
      } else {
        console.error("gowofee",xhr.statusText);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.error("gowofee",xhr.statusText);
  };
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Fk-Affiliate-Id","myid");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Fk-Affiliate-Token","mytoken");
  xhr.send(null);
```

Now I am getting this error:
[image]

Comment: I am trying it from a chrome extension. Can that be a reason?

Comment: its working with goole Crome also .. may be you have problem with Id and Token

Comment: i just tried it in python and it works.. cant figure why it is not working in javascript

Comment: id and token is fine tested with python

Comment: Try adding a CSP rule like shown in the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) and instead of `https://example.com` use `https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net`

Comment: I added this line in manifest.json, error still persists: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net; object-src 'self'",`

Comment: I tried doing same thing to ebay api and it works.

Comment: only flipkart is showing that problem. By the way, why do we need to add a CSP rule for a simple GET request? Is it because we are using HTTPS?

Comment: 1. Try using the standard XHR without async=false and use a callback. 2. Speaking of reasons why the rule is needed it's apparently because even `GET` requests can also leak sensible information via url parameters.

Comment: I am getting this error : `GET https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/search/json?query=Moto%2BG%2B3rd%2BGeneration&resultCount=5 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: Have you more precision for this error ?

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin -sorry, I couldn't get you